# JavaScript wait in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How could I make a JavaScript script wait before executing next line?

I'm aiming for something like this:

```
<script>
const button = document.getElementById("bttn")
button.onclick = function() {


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.onclick = **async** function() {

//code before delay
   
 await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, **however long you want to wait in milliseconds**));

//code after delay

}
```

Please note you MUST have an async function